# How can i transfer the cost of a resource to one of my Bizpark's team member?

Tags: azure, credits, bizspark

We have three developers in my startup and we are members of Microsoft Bizpark.
I am the only back-end developer so i create and control all the resources in our azure portal.

Even though i made the other members as owners of our resources (settings->users) i am still the only one losing credits. I always reach the limit and they always have 150$ left.

Is it possible to transfer the cost of a resource to another member or do i have to create it again from theirs accounts?

Thank you in advance for any response!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an Azure billing question, not a programming question. Open a (free) Azure billing support ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using bizspark also, and there is no way to transfer elements between accounts. Depending on the objects you are planning to move, some of them, you will have to create a backup and restore them in the new account.

Basically, you have to create them again. It's a pain, but if you order your components you can get the most out of the 5 accounts wiht 150 usd.